# Is it possible to provide a custom JSESSIONID value to the container?

Tags: tomcat, jsessionid

I'm referring to the value of jsessionid, not the name of the cookie.

Is it possible to tell container to create a jsessionid with a given "xyz" value?

For example, if jsessionid cookie value is "123" and container does not find it in its datastore, can we configure it to create one with "123" as the jsessionid key? For example, in this scenario the jsessionid cookie will not need to be updated.

I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid different jsessionids for each user facing app behind the same domain. With this approach, all the apps can consume the same "jsessionid" cookie instead of having to maintain individual ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just setup the Session handling at the container level (not the at the default which is the App level).

That way all of the apps will use the same pool of Sessions and the paths for each App (the `Set-Cookie` response header will have a `Path` that points to `/`)

The biggest gotcha with this approach is that what you put into the Session will also need to be accessible at the container level.  This means that you can easily put primitive types into the HttpSession object, but if you attempt to put any class that would be App specific into the HttpSession it will fail.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned. Each app runs on a dedicated (Tomcat) container.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with Jetty?

Comment: I thought if there's a way to do it in Jetty, I could use that as a baseline to figure out a way to do it in Tomcat.

Comment: I removed the Jetty tag, it's inappropriate.